# Environment variables with docker run -e

Tags: docker

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y default-jdk

ADD sample-docker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENV SITENAME="ASDASD"

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

and here is a bit of Java code that i use:

```
@Value("${SITENAME:testsite}")
private String siteName;
```

with this setup everything works good and environment value of SITENAME is indeed "ASDASD". But when i try to set that variable with:

```
docker run -P -d --name spring spring-app -e SITENAME='DOCKERlocal'
```

it doesn't work (value is the one from Dockerfile). What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass the `-e` to the docker command. So:

```
docker run -P -d --name spring -e "SITENAME=DOCKERlocal" spring-app
```

As you are doing it, you are passing it to the image entrypoint.